# Asp RequiredFieldValidator Text property stops displaying but ErrorMessage still displays in validationsummary

Tags: asp.net, webforms, html, lifecycle, requiredfieldvalidator

I am having a problem with a RequiredFieldValidator text property. My asp web form has a Panel. In the overridden OnPreInit I create a table with a textbox and a RequiredFieldValidator and store it into a session variable, on each postback I save the table into this session and load it up. When I run the code the validator is fine. Through each postback the Text property is shown in the table as long as the textbox is not filled in and the validation summary shows the error message. When I fill the textbox in, the validator shows valid which is correct; the Text property is no longer displayed and the validatorsummary no longer shows the error. Then when I delete what's in the Textbox and cause a postback (clicking a button) weird stuff happens. The Error Message displays in the Error Message, and when I debug the RequiredFieldValidator .IsValid is false. But the Text Property never shows back up!? I think I might be missing something with the viewstate, maybe the pre render on the RequiredFieldValidator, or the way I am saving/restoring my session state.

I have tried everything I can think of. Thank you for any help!!!!

**aspx.cs**

```
namespace AccessManagementRepeatingTableAsp
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Data.SqlClient;
        using System.Diagnostics;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Globalization;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Security;
        using System.Transactions;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.UI;
        using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

        public partial class webform : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            private Table testTable = new Table();

            protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
            {            
                if (!this.IsPostBack)
                {
                    TextBox targetTextBox = new TextBox();
                    string targetTextBoxId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    targetTextBox.ID = targetTextBoxId;

                    RequiredFieldValidator targetRequiredValidator = new RequiredFieldValidator();               
                    targetRequiredValidator.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    targetRequiredValidator.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    targetRequiredValidator.ErrorMessage = "programatic";
                    targetRequiredValidator.Text = "testvalidator";
                    targetRequiredValidator.ControlToValidate = targetTextBoxId;
                    targetRequiredValidator.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
                    targetRequiredValidator.Visible = true;

                    TableCell textCell = new TableCell();
                    textCell.Text = "textCell";
                    textCell.Controls.Add(targetTextBox);

                    TableCell validatorCell = new TableCell();
                    validatorCell.Text = "validatorCell";
                    validatorCell.Controls.Add(targetRequiredValidator);

                    TableRow row = new TableRow();
                    row.Cells.Add(textCell);
                    row.Cells.Add(validatorCell);
                    this.testTable.Rows.Add(row);
                    Session["test"] = this.testTable;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.testTable = (Table)Session["test"];
                    RequiredFieldValidator rfv = (RequiredFieldValidator)this.testTable.Rows[0].Cells[1].Controls[0];
                    rfv.Validate();
                    Session["test"] = this.testTable;
                }

                 this.testPanel.Controls.Add(this.testTable);

                RequiredFieldValidator rfv2 = (RequiredFieldValidator)this.testTable.Rows[0].Cells[1].Controls[0];
                rfv2.Validate();
                Page.Validate();

                base.OnPreInit(e);
            }

            protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Page.Validate();
                if (Page.IsValid)
                {
                    this.statusLabel.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                    this.statusLabel.Text = "Status: Valid";
                }
                else
                {
                    this.statusLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    this.statusLabel.Text = "Status: Invalid";
                }
            }
        }    
    }
```

**aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AccessManagement.aspx.cs" Inherits="AccessManagementRepeatingTableAsp.webform" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css">
  div {padding: 0; margin: 0; } /* generated div */
  div.centeredDiv {padding: 0; margin: 0; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;} /* generated div */
  table.tblFormat {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
  td.tdFormat {text-align:left;}
  td.tdHidden {visibility:hidden}
  .centered { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
</style>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Form" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="submitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submitButton_Click" />
        <br />
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="statusLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
    </div>
    <asp:Panel ID="testPanel" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>

    <br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem. When a requiredfieldvalidator is set to valid (.isvalid = true) it adds an attribute key: 'style' value: display:none. Then when the text is removed and the validator is false, the attribute remains. My fix is to hook into the rendering of the validator and always remove this attribute. Then I only write out the error message if the validator is invalid. Here is what I mean:

First redirect the rendering of your validator to your own method:

```
validator.SetRenderMethodDelegate(validator_SetRenderMethodDelegate);
```

Next in the validator_SetRenderMethodDelegate method always remove the 'style' attribute.

```
private void validator_SetRenderMethodDelegate(HtmlTextWriter output, Control container)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        RequiredFieldValidator localRFV = ((RequiredFieldValidator)container);
        RequiredFieldValidator tableRFV = (RequiredFieldValidator)this.testTable.Rows[0].Cells[1].Controls[0];

        string[] keys = new string[((RequiredFieldValidator)container).Attributes.Count];
        localRFV.Attributes.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);
        foreach (string key in keys)
        {
            string current = localRFV.Attributes[key];
            if (key == "style")
            {
                localRFV.Attributes.Remove(key);
                tableRFV.Attributes.Remove(key);
                Session["test"] = this.testTable;
            }
        }

        if (!localRFV.IsValid)
        {
            output.Write(localRFV.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think it is perfect, but it's a step in the right direction.